# custom convolution function in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to use my own convolution function in tensorflow. I have implemented that using numpy. How would I convert the code to Tensorflow format(dynamic inputs in computational graph).

At present my function takes a 2d numpy array as input and produces a 3d numpy array(height, width and output channels). How can I iterate through all the input images?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I am trying something similar and I am also stuck at one point in my kernel implementation. I would like to know more how you solved this.

Comment: Maybe if you post your code it would be easier

Answer (score -3):

What you want does not make sense. Convolution is a [mathematical operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) which is defined in some particular way. It is easily extended in N-dimensions and converted to a discrete case (by summing instead of integration), this is why TF has conv1d, conv2d, and general n-dim convolution.

So it is impossible to define `my own convolution function` in the same way as you can't define your own matrix multiplication function because if it does not calculate the values in exactly the same way, it will no longer be a convolution function.

---

Now if you want to define your own operation, you should take a look at the [official documentation how to define it](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op). In a few words:

- create the op using already written functions
- write stuff in C++